# How to create a shadow gradient for a rectangle in PSD like this one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I would like to create something like this in Photoshop. Any hints? :)

[image]

Comment: Hi loft, welcome to GD.SE! Do you have a more specific question on where you're getting stuck? This looks to be a solid square on the top layer with 2 gradient layers below it.

Comment: Hi AndrewH, Thank you for your feedback. I am getting stuck with the background layers. How can I create the two gradient background layers, which fit the 3d effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a rectangle shape layer, duplicate it, move it down and to
   the left.
2. Select the bottom shape layer. Add an anchor point, convert it to a
   corner point.
3. Click and drag the points to make the back shape.
4. Add a gradient fill, and adjust the angle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For multi-gradient shapes you will need to use multiple gradient layers.

[image: gradient layer]

So have your foreground rectangle on the top layer.

Have the horizontal gradient at the bottom.

Place the vertical gradient in the middle and use a layer mask to hide the left side of the layer to show the gradient layer below it.

[image: brush gif]